# Powershell - Query event 4688 for command line text

Tags: security, powershell, event-log

Regarding powershell and Event4688 where it's now possible to log text entered into a windows command line.

Is there a way to use the powershell Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable to show me what was entered in 'Process Command Line" of the event logs?  This would be the actual text someone entered into the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the properties in an eventmessage using `Properties`, but you need to use a sample event so you can compare the message and the `Properties`-array to find out which index is the right field. I think it is the 9th (index 8), but you should verify.

List properties (values in message):

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
    LogName = 'Security'
    ID = 4688
} -MaxEvents 1).Properties

Value                          
-----                          
S-1-5-18                       
-                              
-                              
999                            
920                            
C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe  
%%1936                         
784                            
           #I believe this is CommandLine                       
S-1-0-0                        
-                              
-                              
0                              
C:\Windows\System32\wininit.exe
S-1-16-16384
```

Using `Select-Object`, you can create your own object to extract ex. the TimeCreated and the CommandLine (using custom/calculated properties):

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
    LogName = 'Security'
    ID = 4688
} | Select-Object TimeCreated,@{name='NewProcessName';expression={ $_.Properties[5].Value }}, @{name='CommandLine';expression={ $_.Properties[8].Value }}

#I didn't have any values in my events

TimeCreated         NewProcessName                   CommandLine
-----------         --------------                   -----------
09.04.2016 00:56:04 C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe               
09.04.2016 00:56:04 C:\Windows\System32\services.exe            
09.04.2016 00:56:04 C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe            
09.04.2016 00:56:04 C:\Windows\System32\wininit.exe             
09.04.2016 00:56:04 C:\Windows\System32\csrss.exe
```

You could also use XML to access the properties, but this would be more useful if you were listing different eventids (were the order in the properties-array would be different). Ex:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
    LogName = 'Security'
    ID = 4688
} | Select-Object TimeCreated, @{name='CommandLine';expression={ (([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'CommandLine' })."#text" }}
```

Comment: thanks for your help!!  How do I parse it even further?  I keep getting a 'cannot index into a null array'.   Left you another question - [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758480/powershell-parsing-select-object-even-further)

Comment: What do you mean by parse it further? Which solution is failing and does the error mention where in the code it is? The only possibility I can think of is ex. `$_.Properties[8].Value`, but I ran this on a computer with no value without errors..

Comment: Solution is awesome and totally answers the question.  I'm just trying to learn this stuff.  Parse it further for example within the command line did someone type 'net shell'  'ftp' etc.  Just trying to learn.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you want to be able to check what the "first word" was (ex. `net`), then split the string to an array and access the first element `$_.Properties[8].Value.Split(" ")[0] -eq 'ftp'`. If you want check if it was "net use" use `-like` or `-match`, ex. `$_.Properties[8].Value -match '^net use'`. If you have more questions about it you need to write a new SO question as this is outside the scope for this question.

Comment: That's what I did -- thought I put the link into the first comment. Hah, great comment that helps too.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it. It was to similar to the blue username next to it. :-)