# Powershell parsing select-object even further

Tags: powershell

So for this script given to me by @Frode F.  how would I parse it down even further?
Here is what @Frode F. gave me --

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
LogName = 'Security'
ID = 4688
} | Select-Object TimeCreated,@{name='NewProcessName';expression={ $_.Properties[5].Value }}, @{name='CommandLine';expression={ $_.Properties[8].Value }}
```

Now how do I parse it down to remove certain events? Here is my code -

```
$search = @("C:\*")
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
LogName = 'Security'
ID = 4688
} | Select-Object TimeCreated,@{name='NewProcessName';expression={ $_.Properties[5].Value }}, @{name='CommandLine';expression={ $_.Properties[8].Value }
}  | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Properties[8].Value -notlike $search}
```

This keeps giving me a cannot index into a null array.

Comment: `select` statement should almost always be the last command in a pipeline...unless you want to export the results to a file that is....   `command  | Where-object | select-object`

Comment: You could use `$_.Properties[8]....` in a where-statement before `select-object` too like @Negorath and @kiran explained, but I would actually do it `select | where` like you've done to avoid writing that horrible `..Propeties[8]....` code twice. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Where-Object` cmdlet is operating on the results piped out from the preceeding `Select-Object` cmdlet.

Try replacing:

```
$_.Properties[8].Value -notlike $search
```

with:

```
$_.CommandLine -notlike $search
```

---

Edit: @Negorath and @Kiran are correct. You'll likely end up with a better performing solution if you re-arrange the pipeline to filter *before* you select.

Comment: This would work, but I would alternatively suggest moving the `Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Properties[8].Value -notlike $search}` to before `Select-Object` in the pipeline.

Comment: This definitely works, didn't realize that CommandLine would become the variable.  I tried puttiing the Where-Object filter in front of Select-Object before and I couldn't get it to work.  Just assumed there wasn't anything  returned from Get-WinEvent that I could use.   Many thanks!!